# What is the optimal --max-requests setting for Starman?

Tags: perl, nginx, dancer, starman

I am running a Dancer (v1.3202) app with Starman (v0.4014) and ngynx as a front end proxy. I am noticing a huge latency spike in my load balancer every couple of hours and wonder if it's the workers reaching their request limit and restarting. The latency goes from 30ms average to 1000ms or more. I checked the MongoDB and there are no long running queries. What does the --max-requests actually do regarding the workers and what happens when a worker reaches this limit?

Comment: FWIW, I strongly recommend [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Perl.html) over Starman. Deeper in every way and more reliable in my experience.

Comment: My experience is different: I have a starman setup which is happily serving more than 100,000,000 requests per day, for many months without problems.

Answer (score 4):

#### What does the `--max-requests` setting do?

From `starman --help`:

> --max-requests
>       Number of the requests to process per one worker process. Defaults
>       to 1000.

What this means is that each worker will exit after it processes that many requests. The master process will then launch a brand new worker for each worker that exits, maintaining the number of workers according to the `--workers` setting.

Using `--max-requests` is usually a good thing, especially if your app isn't the only thing running on the box, because `perl` (notoriously) does not give back memory that it uses. This **recycling** of worker processes is the way `starman` can give memory back for other processes to use. If your app actually *leaks* memory, this can also help keep your app running with good performance as opposed to your app eventually consuming all the memory and needing to be killed by the OS.

#### What is the optimal value for the `--max-requests` setting?

You should leave it at its default value of `1,000` unless you have a good reason to change it. If your app is the only thing running on the box and you're sure that it's not leaky, you could try using a higher value to recycle workers less often. If you know your app is leaky, you may want to use a lower value to recycle workers *more* often. However, generally this setting should actually have very little impact on performance.

That said, recycling workers *could* be responsible for spurious slow requests if your workers cache stuff in memory because new workers would need to spend some time rebuilding those caches, but there could be many other possible explanations. You'll need to do some profiling to find out what's really causing the specific slowness you're seeing.

Comment: What about keep-alive connections? For me it seems that multiple HTTP requests over one keep-alive connection just count as one request. Can you confirm this observation?